# Stream from RxJS promise

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, promise, reactive-programming, rxjs

I'm attempting to run a `reduce` on a stream that I'm creating from a promise.

In the example below, `myApi.getItemsAsync()` returns an array.

I'd expect the `reduce` callback to be called with each individual item in the array. Instead, it's being called with the entire array.

```
Rx.Observable.fromPromise(
  myApi.getItemsAsync()
)
.reduce(function (acc, item) {
  // expecting `item` to be a single item
  // instead, seeing the entire array
}, [])
.subscribe(function (result) { 
  console.log(result);
});
```

If `myApi.getItemsAsync()` was a synchronous function which returns an array, the reduce is working as expected, calling the callback with each item in the array.

How would I get this to work with promises?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[reduce](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/reduce.html) is working on the whole stream, not on the array that is emitted as one part of it.

If you were looking to use the array method, then it should be

```
Rx.Observable.fromPromise(myApi.getItemsAsync())
.map(function(array) {
  return array.reduce(function (acc, item) {
    return …;
  }, []);
})
…
```

If you were looking to use the stream method, then you'll need to inject the array items in the stream first. I guess in your synchronous version you had used [fromArray](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/from.html). Together with a promise, you'd do

```
Rx.Observable.fromPromise(myApi.getItemsAsync())
.flatMap(function(array) {
  return Rx.Observable.fromArray(array);
}).reduce(function (acc, item) {
  return …;
}, [])
…
```

Comment: You can simplify `flatMap` since it will implicitly handle arrays, you don't need `fromArray`

Comment: @paulpdaniels: yeah, I suspected something like that. But I like the explicit way better anyway :-)

Comment: Is there any advantage of this solution over simple `reduce` on returned array (not Rx's `reduce`, but `Array.prototype.reduce`)? I think is worth to consider until Rx has significant overload when doing simple things like this one.

Comment: @ErykNapierała: You mean like in the first snippet? I don't know, I don't think so. And you probably one could avoid Rx completely here and just use the promise.

Comment: Not exactly like on in the first snippet. I thought about `reduce` on array with which promise is resolved. And yes, you could get rid of Rx completely in this simple case, but I assume you don't want to use it without reason and that simple code is only example. Anyway, I see no sense in using Rx for tasks that could be done synchronously, I don't see any advantage in doing this.

Comment: @ErykNapierała: I don't think it makes any difference whether you use `fromPromise(getItems().then(reduce))` or `fromPromise(getItems()).map(reduce)`. Both are async.

Comment: Yes, that's true. My point was `fromPromise(getItems()).flatMap(array => fromArray(array)).reduce()`,which spreads array elements into single values in the stream. So reducer is async but it's created from static collection (array) and this one doesn't make sense for me.

Comment: To clarify, the example was simplified to isolate the actual question. Rest assured that asynchronous control flow was necessary